# Breadboard circuit doesn't pay attention to sensor unless attached to multimeter probe?

Tags: sensor, multimeter, breadboard

Basically I'm using a programmable microchip to turn motors when a QTI infrared sensor reads a black surface. The sensor is connected to an LM293N comparator so that it outputs voltage on a black surface instead of a white surface. My problem is, the chip acts like there's no voltage whatsoever coming from the sensor and my circuit doesn't function. But then, when I connect the positive probe of a multi meter to the positive battery, and negative probe to the comparator output, I do see the correct output voltage and the circuit works properly. I apologize that I don't have a diagram to show, the one supplied by my teacher is slightly wrong so I had to make an alteration to it and I don't want to create more confusion. I hope the photo doesn't confuse you more. Does anyone know why connecting the probes "completes" the circuit?

[image]

Comment: I suggest you urgently reread your question from the eyes of a person that doesn't know jack about your project, and edit it to be a coherent question.

Comment: Could you please supply us with photo's and diagrams if possible. Separate your observations and actions from the questions. If you have a question(s), please end them with (?). What you have right now is very confusing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The LM293 comparator is an open drain output part. What that means is that the part can pull the output low bit not high. You have to add a suitable pull-up resistor to provide the high level output when the comparator shuts it's output transistor off.

When you connected your meter between the comparator output and the positive supply rail the internal resistance of the meter was acting as a pull-up resistor!!

Looking closely at your photo it is fairly clear that you did not provision the LM293 output with a pull-up.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the comments made by @MichaelKaras explaining why your circuit works only when you connect your multimeter from +VCC to the LM293N's OUTPUT pin--i.e., the multimeter unintentionally acts as a resistor when you connect it between +VCC and the LM293N's open-collector OUTPUT pin, it is also worth mentioning (albeit off topic relative to your original question) that many microcontrollers (MCUs) provide an internal pull-up resistor on each digital input pin. Furthermore, these internal pull-up resistors can (usually) be enabled/disabled under software control--e.g., by invoking a library function, or by manually setting/clearing the appropriate bits in a control register.

I assume you are using the LM293N as a voltage threshold detector to produce a digital output signal (i.e., DARK or NOT DARK), and you want to monitor this digital signal using a digital input pin on your MCU. If your MCU provides an internal pull-up resistor, an external pull-up resistor is probably unnecessary. Simply connect a wire directly from the LM293N's OUTPUT pin to the chosen digital input pin on your MCU, and ensure your software activates the MCU's internal pull-up resistor on the chosen digital input pin immediately after the MCU powers ON.

For example, if you are using an Arduino Uno development board and you want to use digital input pin 4 to monitor the digital signal coming from the LM293N's OUTPUT pin, you could do the following:

```
int irSensorPin = 4;

void setup()
{
    // Configure pin 'irSensorPin' as a digital input with the
    // pin's internal pull-up resistor enabled.
    pinMode( irSensorPin, INPUT_PULLUP );
}
```

Of course, if your MCU does not provide an internal pull-up resistor, then you must install a resistor (or other suitable circuit) between +VCC and the LM293N's open-collector OUTPUT pin, where +VCC is the positive voltage rail that supplies power to the MCU (e.g., +5 VDC for the Arduino Uno). You might start with a 10 kohm resistor having a wattage rating of 1/8 Watt (or greater) for this resistor. (For more information, search the Interwebs for "open collector circuits".)

Comment: The internal pullup resistor idea may work for some applications, particularly on a nice PC board with short connections, but it is not the perfect solution. Internal pullups on GPIOs of MCUs usually have a nominal value of 50K ohms to keep down power dissipation on the silicon. It is also common to see them speced in a big range of ohms value from maybe 30K to over 75K. The nominal usage model for these is to bias unused pins so that they are not left floating. These factors in this case mean that the comparator output will have a rather lazy rise time that could vary over a large range.